# Is it possible for a class to expose a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I make a factory "M". I need to construct a class "C". The developer who includes my class 'M', wants to be able to call 'M::getInst()', and have a properly constructed instance of 'C'.

Additionally, I want the writer of 'C' to be able to work with us, by doing absolutely nothing except providing a public constructor, and a single helper method that tells my class 'M' how to find/call that constructor.

Is that possible? The below is what I want to do in principle. The problem is that I see no way in C++ to write the method "types()". It seems impossible to return types (even one!) as a value.

```
struct C {
    String s; Blob b;
    C( String a, Blob b ) : s(a), b(b) {}
    typelist types() {
        return { String, Blob };
    }
};

clas M {
    template<typename T>
    T* getInst() {
        return getInst_imp<T::types()>();
    };

    template<class... Ks>
    T* getInst_imp() {
        return T( getValue(Ks)... );
    }
};
```

Which would be called, by the user, as:

```
C* instance = M::getInst<C>();
```

The reason for this, is that 'C' is built out of components from a fixed set of component types. My class 'M' is the authority on how to initialize them. So it makes sense that, every time a developer wants to create a new flavor of C, why reinvent all existing wheels? They should just tell 'M' what components they need. But how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eric Niebler suggests](http://ericniebler.com/2014/11/13/tiny-metaprogramming-library/) a typelist should be defined as:

```
// A class template that is just a list of types:
template <class... T> struct typelist { };
```

Which you can expose on your class `C`:

```
struct C {
    String s;
    Blob b;
    C( String a, Blob b ) : s(a), b(b) {}
    using types = typelist<String, Blob>;
};
```

Then we can borrow some techniques from Eric's Tiny Metaprogramming Library to use the typelist inside your factory:

```
template<typename T, typename List>
struct MImpl;

template<typename T, typename ...Ks>
struct MImpl<T, typelist<Ks...>> {
    static T getInst() {
        return T(getValue<Ks>()...);
    }
};

class M {
public:
    template<typename T>
    T getInst() {
        return MImpl<T, typename T::types>::getInst();
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Z3y0xpQOsIu48uj4).

Comment: That's perfect! I had tried to do something similar, but I never thought of using the typedef - I was trying to template the classes themselves. I thought it was a dead end, because the "user" needed to specialize them before they could be used.

But the typedef gives C's author a place to store that info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do right now is `std::tuple`:

```
using typelist = std::tuple<String, Blob>;
typelist types() {
    return typelist(s, b);
}
```

Which, depending on what you do, may be better as a `tuple` of references.

Comment: Is tuple still limited to 10 items? We may look for a lib that has a bigger tuple class, or more likely rolling our own tuple...

Do you think there is another way to accomplish this in general? I wonder if I've come up with a bad approach.

Comment: @Saburouta Huh? A tuple has never been limited in number of items.

Comment: @Barry Why do you say *right now*? Are there plans to let one exports a parameter pack in some other ways? Just curious. Thank you.

Comment: @Barry I may have made up that limitation. I recalled running into it in the past. Maybe a particular compiler's initial implementation was once limited to that size?